# Using both CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH and CPack WiX generator

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, cpack

I'm trying to generate msi-package using CPack WiX Generator.

In my `CMakeLists.txt` there is `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` set to `"C:/Program Files/My Project"`. I need to have the full path, because some significant part of project's source code depends on this path. Also, I split the project into some components, one of which is named `core`.

I successfully generate Visual Studio solution using cmake-gui. But when I try to build the project `PACKAGE`, I get the following error:

```
53>EXEC : CPack error : Problem creating temporary directory: D:/Projects/build-Project-MSVC2015/_CPack_Packages/win64/WIX/project-2.3.0-20.AMD64/coreC:/Program Files/My Project
```

The same error occurs, when I leave `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` empty. In that case this variable is initialized by default to `"C:/Program Files/Project_Name"` and the rror is:

```
53>EXEC : CPack error : Problem creating temporary directory: D:/Projects/build-Project-MSVC2015/_CPack_Packages/win64/WIX/project-2.3.0-20.AMD64/coreC:/Program Files/Project_Name
```

Only when I set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to just `My Project` (absent prepending `C:/` or `/`) everything works well. The directory is created as `D:/Projects/build-Project-MSVC2015/_CPack_Packages/win64/WIX/project-2.3.0-20.AMD64/coreMy Project` and msi-package is created.

It seems, that CPack tries to `make DESTDIR="D:/Projects/build-Project-MSVC2015/_CPack_Packages/win64/WIX/project-2.3.0-20.AMD64/core"` install as an intermediate step, but as stated at [cmake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html):

> WARNING: DESTDIR may not be used on Windows because installation prefix usually contains a drive letter like in “C:/Program Files” which cannot be prepended with some other prefix.

Do I misunderstand the usage of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` with CPack WiX Generator? Or is this is specific to Visual Studio? Or is there a workaround for this problem, like forcing `DESTDIR` to be empty (yes, I know that's dangerous)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really was somewhat misunderstanding the usage of CPack. After reading some information on CPack, I managed to create an msi-package the following way.

For Windows-based package installations I turned off the usage of `DESTDIR` by setting [`CPACK_SET_DESTDIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CPACK_SET_DESTDIR.html) to FALSE.

As stated in cmake's documentation on `CPACK_SET_DESTDIR`:

> The most noticeable difference is that without CPACK_SET_DESTDIR,
>   CPack uses CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX as a prefix whereas with
>   CPACK_SET_DESTDIR set, CPack will use CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX as a
>   prefix.

That is, I should set [`CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) variable to appropriate value.

If I set `CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX` to a non-empty value, e. g. to `/My Project` (note the leading `/`), CPack will append this to `C:/Program files/${CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}`. `CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY`, in turn, defaults to `"${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME} ${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}"`. The full install path would be `C:/Program Files/my-project 1.0.0/My Project`, if I set `CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME` to `"my-project"` and `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION` to `1.0.0`.

So, to build an msi-package that will install the program to `C:\Program files\My Project`, I use the following lines in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/Program Files/My Project" CACHE PATH "Install path" FORCE)
...
SET(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR FALSE)
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "My Project")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "")
```

For WiX generator `CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY` may not contain the full path, so `SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})` will not work.

`CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX` seems to be empty by default, so the last line is redundant.